# How to use prepared statements in Stata?

Tags: mysql, stata

I want to use prepared statements in Stata, like in the following (pseudocode) example:

```
for each key in keylist
   odbc load, exec("SELECT * FROM table where tablekey = $key")
   do stuff
end
```

How can I bring the parameter value `key` into my statements? I have tried string concats, local variables etc. but nothing works. I would like to know whether there are prepared statements like in Java (`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE tablekey = ?`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read `help local` in Stata. The local macros start with the single quote (to the left of 1) and end with a closing single quote (to the left of Enter). And then may be `help foreach`. I guess that the right syntax would be

```
   local keylist "the actual list of keys"
   foreach key of local keylist {
      odbc load, exec("SELECT * FROM table where tablekey = `key'")
      save thisdataset`key', replace
   }
```

etc.

(Stata is the only programming environment I know :) ).